# Trouble with understanding a condition upon insert in postgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, ternary-operator

I have this code:

```
temp3=plpy.execute("""insert into tabl(warehouseid, timeo)  
values(%s,%s) returning tablid"""% 
(temp_warehouseid, 0 if not temp_timeo else temp_timeo  if producttypeid==1 else 0))
```

I'm not sure I understad how the the value is inserted to the column `timeo`

The code `0 if not temp_timeo else temp_timeo` is understandable but then we have another condition `if producttypeid==1 else 0` which i'm not sure how it's overwrite the previous value?

I have never seen this kind of coding before in a SQL query.

Specificly in this example:

```
temp_warehouseid = 1
temp_timeo = 2
producttypeid =5
```

This insert the row with values `(1,0)` I assume this is because the `producttypeid=5`? But I don't understand how it works.

Comment: plpy.execute is PL/Python - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-database.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are asking about a python construct.

```
tmp = VALUE1 if CONDITION else VALUE2
```

If the CONDITION is true, then VALUE1 is asigned to tmp. If it's false, the VALUE2 is asigned.

In the case of your query is using two times this python construct.

```
timeo = VALUE1 if CONDITION1 else VALUE2 if CONDITION2 else VALUE3
```

If CONDITION1 is true, value1 is selected. If is false, the the second "statement" `VALUE2 if CONDITION2 else VALUE3` is evaluated.

So, as `temp_timeo = 2`, the condition `not temp_timeo` is false.
And as `producttypeid = 5`, the condition `producttypeid==1` is false.
So the last value `0` is selected.